# Introduce random error to location without losing data

Tags: qgis

I'm working on a project for which I need to insert some uncertainty into a layer of points, to protect the privacy of the data. I tried to do so in QGIS 2.18 as follows:

1. Create a buffer around the original locations, with the maximum random error distance to be assigned to each point (up to 300m).
2. Use the tool "Random points inside the (fixed) polygon", to insert exactly one point in a random location within each created buffer.
3. Create a new buffer around the new points, with the distance fixed in the maximum possible error (300m), to represent the uncertainty in the locations.

PROBLEM: When using these tools, all information in the original attribute table is lost, and I would like to use some of them in the final product. Joining by location is also no longer an option, since there is overlap between buffers (a point would not necessarily be the only one found within within its parent buffer).

QUESTION: Is there a way of joining the information from the original layer with the correspondent modified locations, or maybe a suggestion of a process or alternative tool that does not lead to losing this data on the way?

Comment: This question (https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25877/generating-random-locations-nearby) could give some clue to the problem, but I find all the solutions there very difficult to implement in QGIS Field Calculator, due to its inability to define variables.

Comment: Please do not comment on your own question. Instead, use the [Edit] button to revise the content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the "Differential Privacy" plugin - this does exactly what you're after.